# Why does Hibernate HQL work, but Criteria does not?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, criteria

I have a simple model which is just a chain of one-to-many relationships: Country -< City -< Street
The tables are mapped as entities and are returned as Map.

The following test method is producing odd results:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();

    List<Map<String, Object>> results = null;

    //Query using HQL and print results
    System.out.println("FROM HQL =====================");
    String hql = "from Street where City.Country.countryid = 1";        
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql); 
    results = query.list();
    for(Map<String, Object> row : results) {
        System.out.println(row);
    }

    //Query using Criteria and print results
    System.out.println("FROM CRITERIA ================");
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria("Street");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("City.Country.countryid", 1));
    results = criteria.list();
    for(Map<String, Object> row : results) {
        System.out.println(row);
    }
}
```

The top block which uses the HQL works as expected, but the bottom block falls over:

Output:

```
FROM HQL =====================
{streetname=Mayfair, City=org.hibernate.proxy.map.MapProxy@2b12e7f7, $type$=Street, streetid=1}
{streetname=Park Lane, City=org.hibernate.proxy.map.MapProxy@2b12e7f7, $type$=Street, streetid=2}
{streetname=Bond Street, City=org.hibernate.proxy.map.MapProxy@663b1f38, $type$=Street, streetid=3}
{streetname=Old Kent Road, City=org.hibernate.proxy.map.MapProxy@663b1f38, $type$=Street, streetid=4}
FROM CRITERIA ================
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: City.Country.countryid of: Street
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toColumns(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.BasicEntityPropertyMapping.toColumns(BasicEntityPropertyMapping.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toColumns(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1367)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:457)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getColumnsUsingProjection(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:417)
    at org.hibernate.criterion.SimpleExpression.toSqlString(SimpleExpression.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getWhereCondition(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1578)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:306)
    at com.bar.foo(Main.java:33)
```

I can't see why the HQL can resolve City.Country.countryid but Criteria (Restrictions) can't.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you used the wrong syntax for the hql query.
several faults:

- Street.class instead of "Street"
- Missing alias
- use country directly instead of country.id

Try this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Street.class)
.createAlias("city", "ci")
.add(Restrictions.eq("ci.country", country))
```

See the [hibernate reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! 
I cannot use Street.class because I do not have a Street.class. Everything is dynamic in my application. However the use of the alias appears to have helped.

For each part of the 'path' I can create an alias, like this:
criteria.createAlias("City", "ci");
criteria.createAlias("City.Country, "co");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("co.countryid", 1);

This seems to work.